# static_assert in class to enforce memory layout

Tags: c++

I'm trying use static_assert to make sure other programmers refrain to extend a certain class beyond it's intended usage since it's commonly used in low-level calculations where it's assumed that the number of bytes are as the static assert below wants to check.

```
template<typename T, int N>
class MyClass final
{
public:
    // This is the static_assert I need to fix
    static_assert(sizeof(MyClass<T, N>) == sizeof(T) * N, "Wrong size");

    // rest of code goes here... 
};
```

Unfortunately it does not work with:

```
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<T>::value, "Wrong Size");
```

Since it's still possible after that to pollute the class.

I really want to add this check because if anyone changes this class, i.e. makes it virtual or adds a new member, the results of executing the code at a later stage will be undefined.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code above ill-formed and does not compile.

Comment: That's the reason I posted here :-)
I needed to see how to get write an example that checks the size...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static_assert(sizeof(MyClass<T, N>) == sizeof(T) * N, "Wrong size");`

can not work inside class because `MyClass<T, N>` is incomplete at this point. 
You can move the `static_assert` into ctor/dtor. cons - assert will trigger only at instantiation.
e.g.

```
template<typename T, int N>
class MyClass final
{
public:
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<T>::value, "T has to provide standard layout");

    MyClass()
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(MyClass<T, N>) == sizeof(T) * N, "Wrong size");
        static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<MyClass<T, N>>::value, "MyClass has to provide standard layout");

    }
    T _m[N];
    // rest of code goes here... 
};
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I just need to provide the proper constructors now (i.e. initializer lists etc)
static_assert(sizeof(*this) == sizeof(T)*N, "Wrong size")

Comment: @DecafSux you can use dtor for the same purpose if ctor should be a default